# Power analysis with powerCurve (package simr) gives confusing output

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

In the following example I execute a power analysis on the following dataset:

```
hh <- data.frame(Species=c(rep("SpA", 7),rep("SpB", 5),rep("SpC", 14),rep("SpD", 10),rep("SpE", 1)),
    Skull.length=c(13.100, 14.700, 14.200, 15.400, 15.300, 15.100, 15.200, 11.100, 11.500, 12.900, 12.500, 12.400, 12.700, 12.100, 13.200, 12.300, 11.335, 12.900, 12.500, 13.190, 12.900, 14.400, 14.400, 14.300, 14.100, 14.300, 12.600, 12.900, 12.900, 14.260, 13.670, 14.720, 14.440, 14.440, 15.350, 14.970, 10.300),
    Spine.length=c(59.200, 60.100, 60.600, 67.010, 70.000, 70.300, 70.800, 53.300, 53.800, 54.200, 54.300, 56.900, 55.300, 56.600, 57.800, 57.800, 58.365, 59.900, 60.000, 60.100, 60.200, 62.900, 63.600, 63.700, 66.200, 66.700, 55.300, 55.500, 59.300, 59.740, 61.330, 65.400, 65.600, 65.800, 66.650, 68.030, 52.100))
```

I will need these packages:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest) # a pimped-up version of lme4 which also provides pseudo-p-values.
library(MuMIn) # gives pseudo-R-squared via r.squaredGLMM()
library(pwr) # power analysis for lm
library(simr) # power analysis for generalized linear mixed models by simulation
```

If I were to test the correlation between `Skull.length` and `Spine.length` ignoring the role of `Species` I would do:

```
lm1 <- lm(Skull.length~Spine.length, data=hh)
summary(lm1)$adj.r.squared # 0.7696584
```

Then a power analysis to test if my sample size is large enough would be easy with package `pwr`:

```
p.out <- pwr.r.test(r = sqrt(summary(lm1)$adj.r.squared), sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.8, alternative = "greater")
# To detect r = 0.8773018 or greater with sig.level = 0.05 and power = 0.8, n >= 6 is required
```

But I want to take into account `hh$Species` as in the model below:

```
mem.skull.vs.body <- glmer(Skull.length ~ Spine.length + (1| Species),
                            data=hh,
                            family="gaussian")
```

Which produces:

```
Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   0.73958    1.32239 23.50147   0.559    0.581    
Spine.length  0.20848    0.02173 22.72726   9.593 1.87e-09 ***
```

[image]

*[Data and linear regression with parameters from model `mem.skull.vs.body`]*

The slope of my model, `0.20848`, is my measure of the effect size. To find out the sample size required to detect an effect size of at least 0.1:

```
fixef(mem.skull.vs.body)["Spine.length"] <- 0.1
powerSim(mem.skull.vs.body, nsim=1000)
```

Which gives:

```
Power for predictor 'Spine.length', (95% confidence interval):
      98.90% (98.04, 99.45)
```

This suggests that my sample size (37 individuals, each from one of five species) is plenty for the model I am testing, but when I proceeded to double-check with `powerCurve(mem.skull.vs.body, nsim=1000)` I obtained:

```
Power for predictor 'Spine.length', (95% confidence interval),
by largest value of Spine.length:
   53.8:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 3 rows
   55.3:  5.40% ( 4.08,  6.99) - 7 rows
   57.8:  5.20% ( 3.91,  6.76) - 12 rows
   59.3: 12.30% (10.33, 14.50) - 15 rows
   60.1: 21.50% (18.99, 24.18) - 20 rows
  61.33: 30.60% (27.75, 33.56) - 23 rows
   65.4: 61.40% (58.30, 64.43) - 27 rows
   66.2: 80.00% (77.38, 82.44) - 30 rows
  68.03: 94.80% (93.24, 96.09) - 34 rows
   70.8: 98.40% (97.41, 99.08) - 37 rows
```

Here is a graph for the values above:

[image]

I find this output confusing if not suspicious, because:

- it suggests that I would need a sample of >65 observations to have
  80% chances of detecting an effect size of 0.1, in contrast with the estimates from `powerSim()`;
- the range of values of the x axis is very close to the range of values assumed by  `hh$Spine.length`, which are between 52.1 and 70.8.

It looks very much like function `powerCurve` in its default setting is confusing the size of x values with the sample size. Is there a way to change the setting of `powerCurve`to avoid such confusion?

---

**UPDATE (April 2019):**

**Since I asked this question, the package developers have modified function `powerCurve` to reflect the explanations provided below by [pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943612/pete).**

Comment: Many thanks to the package authors, who promptly modified the functions that confused me to make their use more straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`powerCurve` takes an `along` argument that defaults to the first fixed covariate. Not all variables make sense, as can be seen in this example.

In this case you might add an "observation" variable and run a power curve along that:

```
hh$obs <- 1:37
pc <- powerCurve(mem.skull.vs.body, along="obs")
```

Then `plot(pc)` will give a more intuitive result.

---

If you want even more control over the plot, I would recommend using `summary` to get the raw numbers and then plot them as you see fit. Note that the `nrow` column is only currently available in the github version (or in versions > 1.0.5 if you're reading this in the future).

```
summary(pc)
#    nrow nlevels successes trials mean     lower      upper
# 1     3       3         0    100 0.00 0.0000000 0.03621669
# 2     7       7         0    100 0.00 0.0000000 0.03621669
# 3    11      11         9    100 0.09 0.0419836 0.16398226
# 4    14      14        18    100 0.18 0.1103112 0.26947709
# 5    18      18        32    100 0.32 0.2302199 0.42076686
# 6    22      22        67    100 0.67 0.5688272 0.76080147
# 7    26      26        90    100 0.90 0.8237774 0.95099531
# 8    29      29        91    100 0.91 0.8360177 0.95801640
# 9    33      33        98    100 0.98 0.9296161 0.99756866
# 10   37      37        98    100 0.98 0.9296161 0.99756866
```

Comment: It seems a jump from 22 samples to 26 samples, which makes the power jump from 67% to 90%. It might be better to use default nsim=1000 option or specify increase size to find the proper 80% power level sample size.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might be better to complement pete's answer a little more on the confused explanation.
In Marco Plebani's simulation, the expansion is along "hh$Spine.length", i.e., the "66.2" cannot be understood as the sample size, but the spine's length.
In pete's simulation, the value of hh$obs corresponds to number of samples.
To get the 80% power corresponding sample size, we can refine pete's solution a little bit more:

```
mem.skull.vs.body2 <- update(mem.skull.vs.body, control=lmerControl(check.conv.singular = .makeCC(action = "ignore",  tol = 1e-4))) #disable singular warning message
powerCurve(mem.skull.vs.body2, along="obs", breaks=c(22, 23, 24, 25,26,27))
Calculating power at 10 sample sizes along Spine.length
Power for predictor 'Spine.length', (95% confidence interval),==========================================================|
by largest value of Spine.length:
   53.8:  0.00% ( 0.00,  0.37) - 3 rows
   55.3:  9.90% ( 8.12, 11.92) - 7 rows
   57.8: 18.90% (16.52, 21.47) - 12 rows
   59.3: 48.60% (45.46, 51.75) - 15 rows
   60.1: 78.30% (75.61, 80.82) - 20 rows
  61.33: 92.90% (91.13, 94.41) - 23 rows
   65.4: 99.50% (98.84, 99.84) - 27 rows
   66.2: 100.0% (99.63, 100.0) - 30 rows
  68.03: 100.0% (99.63, 100.0) - 34 rows
   70.8: 100.0% (99.63, 100.0) - 37 rows
```

I don't know why my simulated results differ much with pete's.
I switched to

```
powerCurve(mem.skull.vs.body, along="obs", breaks=c(14,16,17,18,20,22))
Calculating power at 6 sample sizes along obs
Power for predictor 'Spine.length', (95% confidence interval),==========================================================|
by largest value of obs:
     14: 47.00% (36.94, 57.24) - 14 rows
     16: 61.00% (50.73, 70.60) - 16 rows
     17: 83.00% (74.18, 89.77) - 17 rows
     18: 98.00% (92.96, 99.76) - 18 rows
     20: 100.0% (96.38, 100.0) - 20 rows
     22: 100.0% (96.38, 100.0) - 22 rows
```

Then it seems 17 samples suffice to give >=80% power.
To verify with 17 samples.

```
library(dplyr)    
hh17 <- sample_n(hh, size=17, replace=F)

model17 <- lmer(Skull.length ~ Spine.length + (1| Species), data=hh17)
powerSim(model17,nsim=100)
Power for predictor 'Spine.length', (95% confidence interval):==========================================================|
      97.00% (91.48, 99.38)

Test: unknown test
      Effect size for Spine.length is 0.17

Based on 100 simulations, (0 warnings, 0 errors)
alpha = 0.05, nrow = 17

Time elapsed: 0 h 0 m 9 s
```

The sampled result above seems over-optimized. With more simulations, 17 samples might suffice to give more than 80% power.